# Horizontal scrollbar not showing up 

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

Update: i was using overflow-x (it is just that my question was wrong)

The horizontal scrollbar should show in this case, but does not

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; width:400px">
  <div style="float:left; width:300px">abc </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:300px">abc </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

How do i use the div overflow in this case?

Comment: Well I can fix one problem right away. Horizontal scrollies are on the X-axis, so you'll want to be using "overflow-x" anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, your child divs will not cause an overflow of the parent div. Your current design will not cause an overflow of the parent because both children are set with `float:left`

It seems like you are assuming that the children will be stacked horizontally; turn float off and put them in a table of width `600px` in adjacent cells and see what that does.

Also note that the CSS overflow property is highly browser-dependent. Some browsers use `overflow:scroll` and some use `overflow:auto`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a horizontal scrollbar then you need to use `overflow-x: scroll;`. Also the inner children div have to be wider than the parent div for the scrollbars to work. So your code will look as follows:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; width:400px">
  <div style="float:left; width:450px">abc </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:450px">abc </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```